# How to keep every two identical names red if both were clicked consecutively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list items represent names, when clicking any name it turns red then take one second to return black again, but clicking two identical names consecutively make them keep red color, not turning black again

you can imagine it as a memory game, but i tried to make a simple example here of what i am trying to achieve in the original project

This is my code and my wrong trial:

```
const App = () => {
  const { useState } = React;
        const items = [
            {
                name: 'mark',
                id: 1,
                red: false
            },
            {
                name: 'peter',
                id: 2,
                red: false
            },
            {
                name: 'john',
                id: 3,
                red: false
            },

            {
                name: 'mark',
                id: 4,
                red: false,
            },
            {
                name: 'peter',
                id: 5,
                red: false
            },
            {
                name: 'john',
                id: 6,
                red: false
            }
        ];

        const [names, setNames] = useState(items);
        const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null);
        const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState(null)

        const handleItemClick = (item) => {
            setNames(prev => prev.map(i => i.id === item.id ? { ...i, red: true } : i));
            //the problem is here
            setTimeout(() => {
                setNames(prev => prev.map(n => {
                    if (secondName && (secondName.name === firstName.name) && n.name === firstName.name) {
                        return { ...n,red: true }
                    }

                    return { ...n, red: false };
                }))
            }, 1000)

            if (!firstName) setFirstName(item);
            else if (firstName && !secondName) setSecondName(item)
            else if (firstName && secondName) {
                setFirstName(item);
                setSecondName(null)
            }
        }


        return (
            <div class="app">
                <ul class="items">
                    {
                        names.map(i => {
                            return (
                                <Item
                                    item={i}
                                    handleItemClick={handleItemClick}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )

    }


    const Item = ({ item, ...props }) => {
        const { id, name, red } = item;
        const { handleItemClick } = props;

        return (
            <li
                className={`${red ? 'red' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => handleItemClick(item)}
            >
                {name}
            </li>
        )
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

But this code doesn't work correctly, when clicking two identical names consecutively they don't keep red color and turning black again

Comment: Shouldn't your map have a key property on the items?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 yes thank you, but how this will affect the problem??

Comment: you're always returning `red: false` for all not matching items - change state only for matching

Comment: i see, but how to keep ```red: true```, in two both consecutive clicked identical items without  turning again to false??

Comment: add `locked` property to each item? use state to save previous item, compare current, if matching set both to (`red` and) `locked` (not black-able) else both to black (`red: false`?) and clear `previous` - just think in states (series of `what if`)

Comment: yes thank you,i think i have the clue now, i think it is hard but i will try, thank you!

Comment: What is the expected result when a "match" is made?

Comment: @DrewReese 
it is like a memory game, when two cards are the same, the two cards don't flip back again, so when the match is made the two names keep the red colors and don't return black again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems the issue is overloading the event handler and violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

The handler should be responsible for handling the click event and nothing else. In this case, when the element is clicked you want to add the `id` to the state of selected/picked names, and toggle the `red` state value of item with matching `id`. Factor the timeout effect into (*strangely enough*) an `useEffect` hook, with the picks as dependencies. This inverts the logic of the timeout to clearing/resetting the state versus setting what is "red" or not. You can/should also move any logic of determining matches into this same effect (*since it already has the dependencies anyway*).

```
useEffect(() => {
  ... logic to determine matches

  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // time expired, reset only if two names selected
    if (firstName && secondName) {
      setFirstName(null);
      setSecondName(null);
      setNames(names => names.map(name => ({ ...name, red: false })));
    }
  }, 1000);

  // clean up old timeout when state updates, i.e. new selected
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [firstName, secondName]);
```

This will allow you to simplify your name setting logic to

```
if (!firstName) {
  setFirstName(item);
} else {
  setSecondName(item);
}
```

*Note: I believe you need another data structure to hold/track/store existing matches made by the user.*

How this works:

1. Starting from clean state, no names are chosen
2. When first name is picked, `firstName` is null and updated, red state updated
3. Timeout is set (*but won't clear state yet*)
4. When second name is picked, `firstName` is defined, so `secondName` is updated, red state updated
5. If match, add match to state (to keep red)
6. Timeout expire and reset state (go back to step 1)

The following is how I'd try to simplify state a bit more, using an array of selected `id`s that only update if the selected `id` isn't already chosen and 2 picks haven't been chosen yet.

```
const App = () => {
  const [names, setNames] = useState(items);
  const [picks, setPicks] = useState([]);
  const [matched, setMatched] = useState({});

  /**
   * On click event, add id to `picks` array, allow only two picks
   */
  const onClickHandler = id => () =>
    picks.length !== 2 &&
    !picks.includes(id) &&
    setPicks(picks => [...picks, id]);

  /**
   * Effect to toggle red state if id is included in current picks
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    setNames(names =>
      names.map(name => ({
        ...name,
        red: picks.includes(name.id)
      }))
    );
  }, [picks]);

  /**
   * Effect checks for name match, if a match is found it is added to the
   * `matched` array.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    // matches example: { mark: 1, peter: 0, john: 0 }
    const matches = names.reduce((matches, { name, red }) => {
      if (!matches[name]) matches[name] = 0;
      red && matches[name]++;
      return matches;
    }, {});

    const match = Object.entries(matches).find(([_, count]) => count === 2);

    if (match) {
      const [matchedName] = match;
      setMatched(matched => ({ ...matched, [matchedName]: matchedName }));
    }

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (picks.length === 2) {
        setPicks([]);
        setNames(names => names.map(name => ({ ...name, red: false })));
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [names, picks]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {names.map(item => (
          <Item
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
            matches={matched}
            onClick={onClickHandler(item.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const Item = ({ item, matches, ...props }) => {
  const { name, red } = item;
  return (
    <li
      className={classnames({
        red: red || matches[name], // for red text color
        matched: matches[name] // any other style to make matches stand out
      })}
      {...props}
    >
      {name}
    </li>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit name "memory" game]

Comment: Thank you, this is more beautiful code, but i couldn't understand that piece of code ```find([_, count])```, this underscore??

Comment: @CodeEagle Object.entries yields an array of key-value pairs, i.e. `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], ...[keyN, valueN]]`, and I used array destructuring to assign `[key, value]` to function parameters `_` and `count`. In the code above `_` is actually the name key used from the previous step. We need the name for the ultimate result, but not for finding the element with `count === 2`, so *a* convention is to use an underscore to denote it being unnecessary. You can also omit it completely; `([, count]) => count === 2` works as well, though could be a little more confusing to the untrained eye.